# AWS S3 Java SDK V2 Long Term Credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble determining how to prepare Amazon Web Service integration with my application for production. Specifically, I need to be able to have long-term credentials that will work for at a bare minimum several months uninterrupted.

In my application, we've had problems with extremely large files utilized for custom export/import processes. Previously, we had the files stored on the web-host file system for both purposes. Given the nature of the data being processed, these can get to be several gigabytes in size, which has become untenable. So, we've been working on utilizing Amazon S3 for the files. I have everything now in place and functioning as desired - exports are streamed directly to S3 storage, downloads are made from Pre-Signed URLs, and uploads for import are handled with Pre-Signed URLS and then read as an input stream from the S3 storage for processing. So there are no issues I have with the functional usage of the AWS SDK in Java. The problem I have is being able to prepare this for use in a production environment.

During my development, I have utilized temporary credentials as described in the documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-temporary.html. An example of how this is utilized inside the application is as follows:

```
try (S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
    .region(Region.of(getAwsSettings().getAwsPrimaryRegion()))
    .credentialsProvider(software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
        software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsSessionCredentials.create(
            getAwsSettings().getAwsAccessKeyId(),
            getAwsSettings().getAwsSecretAccessKey(),
            getAwsSettings().getAwsSessionToken()
        )
    ))
    .build()
) {
    //Functional code omitted for brevity.
}
```

To clarify the 'getAwsSettings', I put the information found in the ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config files into the application as settings that a user is able to configure.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AwsSettings implements Serializable {
    /*****************************************************************
     * Statics & Enums
     *****************************************************************/

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*****************************************************************
     * Fields
     *****************************************************************/

    /**
     * Credentials file 'aws_access_key_id' field.
     */
    private String awsAccessKeyId;

    /**
     * Credentials file 'aws_secret_access_key' field.
     */
    private String awsSecretAccessKey;

    /**
     * Credentials file 'aws_session_token' field.
     */
    private String awsSessionToken;

    /**
     * Config file 'region' field.
     */
    private String awsPrimaryRegion;
}
```

It works, but the problem I have is that I need to keep re-entering my credentials every few hours. This was perfectly fine for development, but it simply will not work long-term in production. I have no idea when users will be performing operations that relate to S3.

What I've been trying to determine is if there is a standard token generation service for AWS. I have an IAM account with very limited access (S3 only) and that's what I've used to retrieve my session tokens by going to the web. (https://d-xxxx.awsapps.com/start). Is it possible to have the username/password and the SSO Start URL (The AWS IAM Identity Center credentials) to request session tokens through the code on demand?

[image]

There would be no problem if the session tokens were only viable for an hour or two, so long as the code could generate new session tokens for use when required. I have been researching for days and have yet to find anything covering this. So far everything I have found describes the temporary credentials.

I have read the "Learn More" link in the image (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-token.html#sso-configure-profile-token-auto-sso), but it describes doing things via the command line and still utilizing the config/credential files in the web hosts .aws directory. I need something that will be strictly within the application itself.

If I'm approaching this entirely incorrectly I'm willing to go a different route so long as the following needs are met:

1. Users of the application with no connection to AWS are able to utilize S3 services (via the server-side code and pre-signed URLs)
2. Credentials for SDK services can be obtained at any time with no requirements on the part of the application users. No need to contact outside support for AWS access.
3. Configuration and function should be entirely contained within the application. All settings should be configurable by an application administrator, but there can be no expectation of a system administrator needing to perform any operations on the host server itself.

Comment: In most cases you can omit any credential information when initializing the client and allow the default credential chain to do its thing. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html

Comment: Right, but unless I'm reading that incorrectly, it's just doing the exact same thing I have in my question, just finding the viable option. 1 fails, 2 fails, 3 fails, but then 4 succeeds (the credentials/config files) and goes from there. That's actually how I had originally configured things. I changed it to bypass the credentials/config file. In either case, that's still utilizing pre-configured values for AWS_SESSION_TOKEN. The default chain is just finding the viable path to that value. I'm trying to generate an AWS_SESSION_TOKEN in code and not have it set anywhere in the system.

Comment: In a deployed env credentials won't come from SSO like a regular user fetches them. If you want to get your own session token via SSO from the code, you'll need to not pass AWS_SESSION_TOKEN and use the SSO provider https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-sso-credentials.html. You can use `aws configure sso` to configure default credential chains to use SSO.

Comment: That's the problem I have. That documentation says "The aws configure sso-session command only updates the sso-session sections in the ~/.aws/config file." So again, it's the config/credentials files. I want to avoid having those files on my host if at all possible, as I don't have access to the host. I only have application level access following a deployment.

Comment: I am not suggesting you use SSO in your deployed env. I am suggesting to use the default credential chain so that you use SSO for your local usage, and it will still work for your deployed configuration. If it's hosted on an ec2 server you can use an instance-profile role.

Comment: The problem with the hosting is that it's somewhat unknown. In the sense that we have about 6 different production level instances and they are all different, ranging from an EC2 server, to local Tomcat hosting. That's why I'm very focused on application specific configuration rather than environment configuration. But I apologize, I'm not really understanding the main point about the default credential chain. When you say local usage, do you mean for development? I have everything working locally already. AWS connects and all of the S3 services are utilized with no problems.